# how to use priorityqueue to store five biggest number in a map?

Tags: java, priority-queue

There's a question like this:
Input is List Where result is:

```
result {
int id;
int score;
}
```

Output should be a map.
The question is there are a list of students where each of student has at least five scores. We want to output a map where key is the student if and value is the average of studrtns's highest five scores
i figured that I should do priorityqueue overriding the compare function but how specifically do I implement this question in full?

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = PriorityQueue<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(int a, int b) {
            return a-b;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Go through all the map entries, adding all the scores to the priority queue, and anytime the priority queue gets bigger than five elements, remove the smallest element.

Comment: So for the remove, is it pq.poll() or pq.remove(0)?

Comment: It can be either `poll()` or `remove()`, but you don't want to give `remove()` an argument.